# How to save protocol buffer classes directly using GreenDao

Tags: android, orm, protocol-buffers, foreign-key-relationship, greendao

GreenDao provides an [addProtobufEntity](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/Schema.html#addProtobufEntity%28java.lang.String%29) method to let you persist protobuf objects directly.  Unfortunately I can't find much documentation explaining how to use this feature.

Let's say I'm trying to add a foreign key into my Message entity so I can access its PBSender protobuf entity.  Here's my generator code:

```
// Define the protobuf entity
Entity pbSender = schema.addProtobufEntity(PBSender.class.getSimpleName());
pbSender.addIdProperty().autoincrement();

// Set up a foreign key in the message entity to its pbSender
Property pbSenderFK = message.addLongProperty("pbSenderFK").getProperty();
message.addToOne(pbSender, pbSenderFK, "pbSender");
```

Unfortunately the generated code doesn't compile because it is trying to access a non-existant getId() method on my PBSender class:

```
public void setPbSender(PBSender pbSender) {
    synchronized (this) {
        this.pbSender = pbSender;
        pbSenderID = pbSender == null ? null : pbSender.getId();
        pbSender__resolvedKey = pbSenderID;
    }
}
```

**Can anybody explain how relationships to protocol buffer entities are supposed to be managed?**

GreenDao currently only supports Long primary keys.  Does my protobuf object need a method to return a unique Long ID for use as a primary key?

If I remove my autoincremented ID then the generation step fails with this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Currently only single FK columns are supported: ToOne 'pbSender' from Message to PBSender`

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience with greendao.

Comment: What did you place the bounty for? Your answer already describes the actual state and limitations. Do you want a extension for greendao?

Comment: I added the bounty before I posted my answer.  I was just hoping to draw more attention to this question, but it would be awesome if somebody can offer a better answer or provide a greenDAO extension!

Answer (score 2):

The [greenDAO generator Entity source code](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/Entity.java#L171) suggests it currently does not support relations to protocol buffer entities:

```
public ToMany addToMany(Property[] sourceProperties, Entity target, Property[] targetProperties) {
    if (protobuf) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Protobuf entities do not support realtions, currently");
    }

    ToMany toMany = new ToMany(schema, this, sourceProperties, target, targetProperties);
    toManyRelations.add(toMany);
    target.incomingToManyRelations.add(toMany);
    return toMany;
}

/**
 * Adds a to-one relationship to the given target entity using the given given foreign key property (which belongs
 * to this entity).
 */
public ToOne addToOne(Entity target, Property fkProperty) {
    if (protobuf) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Protobuf entities do not support realtions, currently");
    }

    Property[] fkProperties = {fkProperty};
    ToOne toOne = new ToOne(schema, this, target, fkProperties, true);
    toOneRelations.add(toOne);
    return toOne;
}
```

However, I suspect that you could make this work if your Protobuf class contains a unique long ID and a `public Long getId()` method to return that ID.